# How can I set value of a data variable on if condition

Tags: vue.js

How can I set value of a data variable on if condition (if normal is selected then x = 3.3 else x = 4.5) how to do this in vue

Comment: You can use vue `watch`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

Answer (score 2):

You can use a computed property `x`:

```js
// In your component
computed: {
    x: function () {
        return this.isNormalSelected ? 3.3 : 4.5
    }
}
```

Where `this.isNormalSelected` can be replaced with a condition that determines if "normal is selected".